# Array as an argument of a function

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

I have 2 2-dimensional arrays and a function.

I would like that function to take the array as an argument.

I tried code like this:

```
var array1:array[1..10,1..10] of integer;
    array2:array[1..20,1..10] of integer;
function name(var my_array:array of array of integer, n:integer);
function name(var my_array:array[1..n,1..10] of integer;const n:integer);
```

But I got errors while trying to compile the code. Any tips?

If you would like me to paste error codes for each version please leave a comment with a request.

For

```
function name(var my_array:array of array of integer, n:integer);
```

The error code is: "Incompatible type for arg no. : Got "Array[0..10] of Array[0..10] of SmallInt", expected "Open array od SmallInt" every time I call the function.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't declare the function in both ways at the same time :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your own type, and then use that type as the parameter to your function. Instead of passing the array dimensions, use the `Low` and `High` functions from the `System` unit; they will work with both static (pre-declared) and dynamic arrays, and avoid hard-coding array sizes and iterators.

You want to avoid hard-coding integer indexes, becaue static arrays in Pascal don't have to start with index `0`; the following is a perfectly legal Pascal array declaration, where the array bounds are from index `-3` to `3`:

```
var
  Arr: array[-3..3] of Integer;
```

Here's an example using a dynamic array (`array of array of Integer`) that loops through the two dimensional array and sums the values; it initializes a 5 x 5 array, populates it with data, and then calls the `SumTwoDimIntArray` function to sum the values.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TTwoDimIntArray = array of array of Integer;

function SumTwoDimIntArray(Arr: TTwoDimIntArray): Integer;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    for j := Low(Arr[i]) to High(Arr[i]) do
      Result := Result + Arr[i][j];
end;

var
  MyArr: TTwoDimIntArray;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(MyArr, 5);
  for i := Low(MyArr) to High(MyArr) do
  begin
    SetLength(MyArr[i], 5);
    for j := Low(MyArr[i]) to  High(MyArr[i]) do
      MyArr[i][j] := j + 1;
  end;
  WriteLn(Format('Sum is %d', [SumTwoDimIntArray(MyArr)]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

You shuld use a new type in these situations . like the following:

```
Type
     vector = array [1..20,1..20] of integer;
var array1:vector;
array2:vector;
function name(var my_array:vector, n:integer);
function name(var my_array:vector;const n:integer);
```

Comment: I upvoted this for its near compliance with Standard (ISO7185) Pascal. Note that full compliance requires unique function names, and doesn't recognize the const keyword in a parameter list.