# Pascal: how to pass arrays to subprograms?

Tags: pascal, procedure

I made a program that has a procedure with an array as one of it's parameters

```
program something ;

const someArray: array[1..4] of integer = (1, 2, 3, 4);

procedure name(someArray: array; a, n: integer);
    begin
    ....
    end;

begin
name(someArray, x, y)
end.
```

After compiling the program I get an error: 
 Fatal: Syntax error, OF expected but ; found (function name() is highlighted)

Why isn't this program working?

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057974/array-as-an-argument-of-a-function

Comment: Open arrays are dialect dependent. If you use Delphi or something compatible like Lazarus the term is open array  name(somearray:array of integer;...);

Comment: Why are you naming your array argument to your function the same as your constant array (`someArray`)? Although scope may be understood, it unnecessarily introduces some confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your parameter properly, as an open array. You find the bounds of the array by using `Low` and `High`.

Here's a (useless but working) example:

```
program Sample;
Var x,y: Integer;

const
  SomeArray: array[1..4] of Integer = (1, 2, 3, 4);

procedure Name(const AnArray: Array of Integer; const A, B: Integer);
var
  OutOne, OutTwo, i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(AnArray) to High(AnArray) do
  begin
    OutOne := AnArray[i] * A;
    OutTwo := AnArray[i] * B;
    WriteLn('One: ', OutOne, ' Two: ', OutTwo);
  end;
end;

begin
  //x and y have to be initialised before use
  Name(SomeArray, x, y);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement Ken White's answer, in straight up (pre-open array) Pascal, `array` on its own in a parameter definition is unsupported.

Instead you need to declare a specific array type to do what you are trying to do here.

Here's what that could look like:

```
program something ;

type
  TMyArray = array[1..4] of integer;

const someArray: TMyArray = (1, 2, 3, 4);

procedure name(someArray: TMyArray; a, n: integer);
    begin
    ....
    end;

begin
name(someArray, x, y)
end.
```